# Angular CDK connected overlay not repositioned when overlay origin changes

Tags: javascript, angular, overlay, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I'm trying to use the Angular CDK's overlay by triggering a `cdkConnectedOverlay` from a `cdkOverlayOrigin` as a very lightweight solution to add template-only overlays. This works nicely.

However, if I try to reuse the same `cdkConnectedOverlay` for different `cdkOverlayOrigin` by changing the overlay origin to which the connected overlay is bound, the overlay is not repositioned.

I set up a minimal example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vet83?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Clicking a button sets the `cdkOverlayOrigin` of the overlay to the button that was clicked.

Click on either button, and the first time the overlay is positioned correctly. However the position of the overlay remains the same no matter which button (i.e. overlay origin) is clicked afterwards.

Did I do something wrong or might this be a bug in the Angular CDK Overlay that changes on the `cdkOverlayOrigin` are not being applied?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a bug. I reported this as an issue https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9353

Comment: Yes, maybe it's a bug. Overlay is created only once

Comment: Yes, And it doesn't readjust based on screen resize.